# MySQL cant write to file permission

Tags: mysql, linux, file, ubuntu, permissions

I have MySQL 8 running on a Ubuntu machine and im trying to execute the following query:

SELECT * FROM test.t_test INTO OUTFILE "/data/mysql/uploads_mw_ebp/test.txt" CHARACTER SET UTF8;

but I keep getting the following error: Error Code 1: Can´t write to file '/data/mysql/uploads_mw_ebp/teste.txt' (OS errno 13 - Permission denied).

I have gave full permissions (**777**) to the directory /data/mysql/uploads_mw_ebp/ and the mysql user has full privileges (including **File** privileges).

The previous directory is the same that is configured for secure-file-priv.

Why I keep getting permission denied?

Comment: see if set: **show variables like 'secure_file_priv';**.
if set you can only write to this dir.
see also if you have FILE permission in MySQL Privs set.
read: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/select-into-outfile/

Comment: I have the variable secure_file_priv set to the same dir and the user has file permission set.

Answer (score 1):

Apparmor on Debian/Ubuntu (SELinux on RedHat or similar distros) often limit these accesses too.
You can try to edit the profile or to test, you can also temporary disable it.

Comment: I have disabled SELinux and AppArmor.